# it's impossible embeding google trends result in jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, ipython, jupyter-notebook, google-trends

I want to embed google trends result in my jupyter notebook cell. 
there are already few ways to do it. but, it doesn't rendered it in a cell, it rendered on browser(make new html)

i want to show it in a cell. like `%matplotlib inline`

my code

```
from IPython.display import display,Javascript
display(Javascript("""trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("TIMESERIES", 
{"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"keras","geo":"","time":"today 5-y"},
{"keyword":"tensorflow","geo":"","time":"today 5-y"},    
{"keyword":"theano","geo":"","time":"today 5-y"}, 
{"keyword":"sklearn","geo":"","time":"today 5-y"},    
{"keyword":"pytorch","geo":"","time":"today 5-y"}],"category":0,"property":""},
{"exploreQuery":"date=today 5-y,today 5-y,today 5-y,today 5-y,today 5-y&q=keras,tensorflow,theano,sklearn,pytorch","guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"});""",
lib='https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/1225_RC03/embed_loader.js'))
```